# monodevelop 3.0.4.2 on windows and mono.2.10.8 issues with MVC4

Tags: windows, mono, asp.net-mvc-4, monodevelop

I'm happily bin deploying an mvc4 beta website with monodevelop to appharbor on my mac and its a nice experience.

However I decided to fire up my windows machine and use the same tooling to work on windows and well its not quite as smooth.

Debugging using the monosoft debugger I get the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult) [0x00046] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.8\mcs\class\System\System.Net\HttpWebRequest.cs:824
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.8\mcs\class\System\System.Net\HttpWebRequest.cs:836

I have tried every type of WebRequest/WebClient combo to get round this but the timeout is immediate. the same code on mac o/s is fine and works ok in production.

I have installed mozroots --sync and have tried every stable and beta/alpha version of the framework and monodevelop on windows and I just cant get a working development environment going.

[image: The runtime used by monodevelop]

[image: The bin deployed dll's that work over on Mac OS and appharbor]

If anyone has any ideas I would be grateful.

Comment: tried running the monodevelop.exe from mono itself but that crashed.

Comment: making sure that close and dispose are called etc.

Comment: I think MVC4 is too bleeding edge for Mono nowadays, nevertheless there's a GSoC student working on that this summer, you may want to ask around in irc://irc.gnome.org/#monodevelop

Comment: Mmm found these:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2992
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3374

Comment: Have you tried creating a dummy project and testing to see if you can get WebRequest to work?

Comment: If you were to fire up wireshark, do you see any network activity where you expect there to be some?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012963/restsharp-in-mono-project-monodevelop

Comment: sorry didnt mean to just link off to another question. good ideas about file new project and wireshark. will have to give both of those a go at some point.