# RestSharp in Mono project (MonoDevelop)

Tags: mono, httpwebrequest, monodevelop, restsharp

I'm doing some Mono project (Mono 2.10.8) and trying to use RestSharp. As I saw on RestSharp page it support Mono.

I'm trying to run following simple code :

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.go2board.com");
var request = new RestRequest();
var result = client.Execute(request);
```

But everytime when I choose Mono 2.10.8 runtime in MonoDevelop IDE I'm getting following error

```
{System.Net.WebException: The request timed out   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00046] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.8\mcs\class\System\System.Net\HttpWebRequest.cs:824    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.8\mcs\class\System\System.Net\HttpWebRequest.cs:836    at RestSharp.Http.GetRawResponse (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00000] in C:\Users\Renato\Desktop\restsharp-RestSharp-8763a56\restsharp-RestSharp-8763a56\RestSharp\Http.Sync.cs:142 }
```

If I switch to .NET runtime in MonoDevelop, everything works fine and I get result as expected.

I also download the RestSharp source code, compile it agains Mono 2.10.8 and tried again, but with no success.

So, can I use RestSharp in my Mono application, and if I can, how? Am I missing something? Some step?

Also, I analyzed RestSharp.dll through Mono MOMA analyzer and I got positive result, which means that I can use RestSharp on Mono.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836287/monodevelop-3-0-4-2-on-windows-and-mono-2-10-8-issues-with-mvc4

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I don't recommend using Mono on Windows, test in Linux first

Comment: I did, and it works as expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as confirmed by rjovic, this may be a bug in **Mono *for Windows***.

Really, Mono is recommended only for non-Windows platforms. It makes sense, especially because for Windows platforms you always have MS.NET ;)